# Reg: String conversion issue

Tags: c, c-strings, undefined-behavior, long-integer, data-conversion

Please find a sample code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () {
    
char *str = "2160000000";
long int evid=0;
evid = atol(str);
printf("%s = str\n",str);
printf("%ld = ev_id",evid);
   return(0);
}

OUTPUT : 

2160000000 = str
-2134967296 = ev_id
```

So, you can see that the str is set to have the value 2160000000 which is greater than a int variable. So i am using a long variable and trying to convert the string to long and store it in the long variable. But for some reason the value is stored as "".

Can you please guide me on what I have missed?

Comment: How big is your `long`? A 32-bit `long` couldn't hold 2160000000. (`long` is typically 32-bits in Windows.)

Comment: I am sorry but how would i know that ?

Comment: Assuming an 8-byte long size, the problem is you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`.  As a result, `atol` was implicitly taken to return an `int` rather than a `long`.  Didn't your compiler give you a warning?  It should have.  In any case, add `#include <stdlib.h>` and recompile and it should work.  But if your machine has 4-byte longs then it won't fit.

Comment: `printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT );`. `printf( "%ld\n", LONG_MAX );` would give you the max value. (`#include <limits.h>` needed.)

Comment: Even if you properly include `stdlib.h` (which you should), you're still hedging the bet that `long` is bit-wider than `int`, which is speculative, especially on a 32bit toolchain. `printf("sizeof int = %zu, sizeof long = %zu\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(long));` at the top of your program would probably be enlightening. And [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/eff3Gdzqh) for what can happen with x86 vs x64 builds.

Answer (score 4):

> I am sorry but how would i know that ?

You could run this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("On this computer,\n");
    printf("type int has %d bytes (%d bits) and range %d to %d\n",
        (int)sizeof(int), (int)sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("type long has %d bytes (%d bits) and range %ld to %ld\n",
        (int)sizeof(long), (int)sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);


    printf("type unsigned int has %d bytes (%d bits) and range 0 to %u\n",
        (int)sizeof(unsigned), (int)sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT, UINT_MAX);
}
```

On my computer this prints:

```
On this computer,
type int has 4 bytes (32 bits) and range -2147483648 to 2147483647
type long has 8 bytes (64 bits) and range -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
type unsigned int has 4 bytes (32 bits) and range 0 to 4294967295
```

But there are plenty of computers (including, it sounds like, yours) where the middle line would be

```
type long has 4 bytes (32 bits) and range -2147483648 to 2147483647
```

But you should be able to use type `long long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits on any machine, and therefore able to represent your number 2160000000 without difficulty:

```
printf("type long long has %d bytes (%d bits) and range %lld to %lld\n",
    (int)sizeof(long long), (int)sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
```

Comment: Re “guaranteed to be at least 64 bits… therefore able… without difficulty”: The C standard makes no specification about how difficult it is for the implementation. 

Comment: On this computer,
type int has 4 bytes (32 bits) and range -2147483648 to 2147483647
type long has 4 bytes (32 bits) and range -2147483648 to 2147483647
type unsigned int has 4 bytes (32 bits) and range 0 to 4294967295

Comment: For me both long and int have the same range.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar Did you try `long long`?

Comment: type long long has 8 bytes (64 bits) and range -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

Comment: So try changing to `long long int evid;`, `evid = atoll(str);`, and `printf("%lld = ev_id",evid);`.

Comment: So does this mean the compilation is on 32 bit and not 64 bit ?

Comment: No, it does not mean that.

Comment: These days, "32 bit" versus "64 bit" typically pertains to *pointers*.  Try `printf("type void * has %d bytes (%d bits)\n", (int)sizeof(void *), (int)sizeof(void *) * CHAR_BIT);`

Comment: Indeed: MS VC has 32-bit `long` on both 32-bit and 64-bit compiler versions. @Vimal if you need a specific size of variable you can use `int64_t`, but note that your `2160000000` will fit a 32-bit `unsigned` integer.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar: The terms “32 bit” and “64 bit” are vague. There are multiple parts of a processor a computer system that can have different widths: Bus transfer width, processor register width, physical address space, virtual address space, instruction size, widths of various integer types in various programming languages. Outside of a context where it is established what you are referring to, it is not useful to call an implementation “32 bit” or “64 bit” without being specific.

Comment: i used cc -m64 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you need to include header `<stdlib.h>` where the function `atol` is declared.

As for the problem then it is evident that in the used system an object of the type `long int` is unable to represent the number `2160000000`. It seems `sizeof( long int )` is equal to `4` and the maximum positive value that can be represented in an object of that type is equal to the value produced by the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "sizeof( long int ) = %zu\n", sizeof( long int ) );
    printf( "LONG_MAX = %ld\n", LONG_MAX );
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( long int ) = 4
LONG_MAX = 2147483647
```

You could use for example function `atoll` but neither the function
`atol` nor the function `atoll` reports whether the conversion was successful. From the C Standard (7.22.1 Numeric conversion functions)

> 1 The functions **atof**, **atoi**, **atol**, and **atoll** need not
> affect the value of the integer expression **errno** on an error. **If
> the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is
> undefined.**

It is better to use function `strtol` instead of `atol` because the first one reports whether conversion was successful and depending on the result you could try to use another function designed for a larger integer type.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *str = "2160000000";

    errno = 0;

    long int evid = strtol( str, NULL, 10 );

    if (errno == ERANGE)
    {
        printf( "Number %s can not be represented "
            "in an object of the type long int.\n", str );

        errno = 0;

        unsigned long int evid = strtoul( str, NULL, 10 );

        if (errno == ERANGE)
        {
            printf( "And in an object of the type unsigned long int\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "But can be represented "
                "in an object of the type unsigned long int.\n" );

            printf( "%s = str\n", str );
            printf( "%lu = ev_id\n", evid );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%s = str\n", str );
        printf( "%ld = ev_id\n", evid );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Number 2160000000 can not be represented in an object of the type long int.
But can be represented in an object of the type unsigned long int.
2160000000 = str
2160000000 = ev_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of garbage value for the `ev_id` variable comes from that the **long int** in c  ( the 32-bits long int ) holds maximum value of `+2,147,483,647` on which is less than the provided string `+2,160,000,000` , so the provided string numeric cannot fit into this datatype.
so you can use **unsigned long int** that holds maximum value of `+4,294,967,295`  ( 32-bits unsigned long int ) ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str= "2160000010"; // Example string
    unsigned long int number;
    number = strtoul(str, NULL, 10);
    printf("%lu\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

output : 2160000010